# Go-to-top button completely dissapears on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put go-to-top button in the bottom right angle of the screen. It should appear on scroll function, a disappear when I go back to top.
The button exists, but when I scroll down, it stays with "home page", so as I scroll more, it is not visible anymore. How to fix the problem? You can see my codes down here. Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
window.onscroll = function(){goTop()};

let goTop = function() {

  var rocket = document.querySelector(".go-to-top");
  var scrollExt = document.body.scrollTop;

  if(document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500){
    rocket.style.display = "block";
  } else{
    rocket.style.position = "none";
  }
    
};

let rocketClick = function() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
.go-to-top{
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.go-to-top i{
   font-size: 50px;
 }

.go-to-top:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!--the rest of markup-->
<div class="rocket">
  <a href="#" class="go-to-top">
   <i class="fas fa-rocket"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!--closing markup-->
```

Comment: `rocket.style.position = "none";` - that is not a valid `position` value; presumably you meant to set the `display` property here instead, to do the opposite of what happens in the `if` branch …

Comment: if got the question right you should use `rocket.style.display= "none";` in your js file

Answer (score 0):

`rocket.style.position:none` would give your element the css style of `position:none`. `none` is not a valid value for the `position` property.

You can see the position values here -> [CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

By the look of your code you would need to use `display` instead of `position`.

Also, you make a variable `scrollExt` and you do not use it. Plus, you make a `rocketClick` function but you do not call it on your element.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  goTop();
};

const goTop = function() {
  const rocket = document.querySelector('.go-to-top');
  const scrollExt = document.body.scrollTop;

  if (scrollExt > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
    rocket.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    rocket.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

const rocketClick = function() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};
```

```css
main {
  height:1500px;
  background:red;
}
.go-to-top{
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.go-to-top i{
   font-size: 50px;
 }

.go-to-top:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<div class="rocket" onclick=rocketClick()>
  <a href="#" class="go-to-top">
   rocket icon
  </a>
</div>
```

Suggestions :

1. Keep using `let` and `const`. Do not use `var`. Also, use `const` for your functions. You do not change the content of the functions anywhere so you can use `const` instead of let.
2. Add an animation(transition) to the `scrollTop`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I tried to fix things but still it doesn't work for me... I accidently left VAR instead of LET, and I use LET because I'm not sure when to use LET and when to use CONST. I tried to add event listeners with this code which you wrote to me in JS. The rocket appears and still "stays" with home page. I also didn't understand you, how I could put an animation on scrollTop?

Comment: @Vlada as you can see in my answer. The basic functionality works. When you scroll over 500px the rocket appears, when you click it, you go top and the rocket disappears . Please be sure you made all the changes. Try to read about `let` and `const`. The basic idea is that you use `let` when you will change the value of the variable in the future eg: `let a=b` //some code// `a=b+1`. And you use `const` when you don't change it's value. But there is more to it than this. You find info about it on the web and also about animated scroll ( just search it on google )

Comment: Yes, basic functionality works, but this is not good yet. Maybe I wasn't precise. At first, I made this basic functionality, than while changing the code, I made mistakes with using VAR etc., but I still cannot make this rocket to be fixed at one point of the screen (right bottom angle) when it shows up. So rocket works, it appears, disappears, take me to the top, but it's not fixed. I wrote whole code exactly like you did but still not fixing at one point. :(

Comment: @Vlada can you explain please, in detail ( maybe edit your original question ) what the desired behavior is ? Now the rocket is fixed in the bottom right corner of the screen when it's visible.

Comment: Ok, let me see… My aim is to put a rocket in the corner of the screen. The rocket is already in the corner, but not "floating". In other words, it doesn't stays in the right bottom corner when I scroll, it's not "stuck" in the corner. Instead of that, it goes up with the "home page" (I made one-page site which you only need to scroll). I want the rocket being fixed through all pages while I scroll to the bottom of the site. Note that I'm using exactly the same code which you wrote for me. If the code works, I don't have a clue why it doesn't work on my computer. I run it on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: did you check my answer? does it work as you want? ( my answer, not on your website ) . If the button has position fixed it stays in the position you set it in relation to the screen.